# Convergence of Newton method

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I have showed using Taylor's theorem that the error after n iterations $e_n$ satisfies $e_{n+1}=Ce_n^2.$

I am now asked to show that to guarantee an error of less than $10^{-M}$ we need approximately $\log_{10}(M) $ iterations. 
How would I go about showing this?

Comment: Are you sure of that? I would expect you need about $\log_2(M)$ iterations, which is more than three times what you write.

Comment: Deliberate self-dup? Not nice.

Answer (score 0):

$|Ce_{k+1}|\le|Ce_k|^2$ implies $$10^M\sim|Ce_n|\le|Ce_0|^{2^n}$$ which will give with twice applying the logarithm give an a-priori estimate of the step number.